# Swift 3: How can I shorten an optional check coupled with a condition check of that optional?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Consider this example. The else if condition checks on the string object looks big and chunky.

```
class A { var bObject =  B() }

class B { var cObject = C() }

class C {
    var flag = FALSE
    var stringObj: String? = "Hello"
}

var aObject = A()

if aObject.bObject.cObject.flag == TRUE {

    //do something
    }
else if aObject.bObject.cObject.stringObject != nil && aObject.bObject.cObject.stringObj!.characters.count > 0 && aObject.bObject.cObject.stringObj! == "Hello" {

    //do something
}
else {

}
```

I'd like to use something like the one below, where the optionally bound variable is used in the same conditional check. But the code wouldn't compile for obvious reasons

```
else if let unwrappedOptional = aObject.bObject.cObject.stringObj && unwrappedOptional.characters.count > 0 && unwrappedOptional == "Hello" {

    //do something
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Comment: use the comma `,` instead of `&&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use condition with `if let` this way.

```
else if let unwrappedOptional = aObject.bObject.cObject.stringObj, unwrappedOptional == "Hello" {

    //do something
}
```

**Note:** No need to compare `characters.count` to `0` because "do something" will only execute if `unwrappedOptional` is equal to `Hello`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code like this:

```
class A { var bObject =  B() }
class B { var cObject = C() }
class C {
    var flag = true
    var stringObj: String? = "Hello"
}

var aObject = A()

if aObject.bObject.cObject.flag == true {

} else if let unwrappedObj = aObject.bObject.cObject.stringObj, !unwrappedObj.isEmpty, unwrappedObj == "Hello" {
    //do something
} else {

}
```

As @NiravD said, there is no need for the `!unwrappedObj.isEmpty` but i'm just putting it here because your `.count > 0` line is also sorta ugly.